# Oracle APEX - text next to icon in select list

Tags: oracle, frontend, backend, oracle-apex, apex

does someone know how to put a text next to or instead of the icon of a select list of an element in Oracle APEX. For example I use the icon "calender search", how do I put the word "month" next to or instead of the icon.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

The component "Popup LOV" supports icons declaratively if the list of values is created as a shared component.
Example:

- create a List Of Values shared component with source:

```
WITH vals (rv, dv, icon) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'foo', 'fa-user' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'bar', 'fa-user' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT rv, dv, icon FROM vals
```

and map column "icon" to value "Icon" in the column mapping section.

- Use this as a shared component source for your list of values (needs to be Popup LOV)

[image]